# How can I toggle a panel's visibility using a CheckBox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have an `<asp:CheckBox>`, and I need to apply a JavaScript call upon it. The JavaScript function should set the visibilty of an `<asp:Panel>` to be true if the `CheckBox` is checked. The visibility of the panel should be false if the `CheckBox` is not checked.

I wasn't able to reach the JavaScript function using an `<asp:CheckBox>` with a normal `input:type = checkbox` it worked. But I need it to be an `<asp:CheckBox>`!

Comment: will jquery work for you instead of javascript ?

Comment: Is the 'panel' and asp:Panel or just and standard div?  Also, are you using jQuery or just plain javascript?

Comment: jquerry will work fine! the panel is asp:Panel !

Answer (score 4):

If i understand you correctly I would personally use jquery then you can do something like this

```
    $("#yourCheckBoxId").change(function(){
       if($(this).attr('checked')){
          $(".yourDivClass").show();
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `CheckBox` has a `runat="server"` attribute, you need to do something like:

```
$("<%= MyCheckBox.ClientID %>").change(function () {
    $("<%= MyPanel.ClientID %>").toggle();
});
```

The code above assumes that your `CheckBox` and `Panel` will always have the same state. That is, a `checked` `CheckBox` equals a visible `Panel`. If you need to modify this code (change the conditions under which the `Panel` is visible, etc.), and want to reference the current `checked` state of your `CheckBox`, simply do this inside your `change()` function:

```
var checked = $(this).prop("checked");
```

**Note:** For future compatibility, it's important to use the `prop()` function instead of `attr()`. The difference here is subtle, but `attr()` will return the state of the `CheckBox` **when it was first loaded on the page**. `prop()` will return **the current state of the `CheckBox`**.

Comment: that is interesting abou thte use of prop(). Do you have a reference with more details? thanks

Comment: @Russell The notes under [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) on the jQuery website mention the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle_panel(chkbox)
{
    var panel=document.getElementById('<%=panle1.ClientID %>');
    chkbox.checked ? panel.style.display='inline':panel.style.display='none';
}
```

Just make a call to the javascript function,inorder to access a asp.net control from javascript it should be made invisible using style attribute , because javascript will return undefined if   Visible="false" is used.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxPanel" runat="server" onclick="toggle_panel(this);" Text="Show" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="panle1" runat="server" Style="display: none">
        Iam Text Inside the Panel
    </asp:Panel>
```